# Githubリモートマスターにローカルブランチを反映させたい

Tags: git, github

ローカルのブランチfeat/mapの最新版commitの14450f3をリモートのマスターに反映させるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 14450f3より前のコミットはmasterにマージせず14450f3**だけ**をマージしたいということですか？

Comment: はい、そうです。　前のコミットもmasterにマージする方法も教えてください。一般的は前のコミット全部mergeさせるのが基本ですか？

Answer (score 1):

gitにはcherry-pickと呼ばれる方法で特定のコミットだけ適用することができます。
https://rfs.jp/server/git/gite-lab/git-cherry-pick.html

そのためmasterから新しくブランチを作成して特定のコミットを適用したブランチを作成してそれをマージするという流れになります。

具体的には以下のようになると思います

```
#マスターブランチに切り替え
$ git checkout master 

#マスターブランチからcherry-pickを実行するfeture branchを作成
$ git branch hotfix-cherry-pick

#作成したfeture-branchに切り替え
$ git checkout hotfix-cherry-pick

#cherry-pickを実行
$ git cherry-pick 14450f3 
#この際にもしかしたら衝突が発生するかもしれません。その場合は通常のコンフリクトと同様に処理してください
```

これをすることで特定のコミットを適用したブランチが作成されるので
あとは通常のブランチと同様にリモートにpushしてマージの流れになります。